# Uniform Acceleration - Does the Reason explain the assertion?

Tags: kinematics

Can you please help with the following question?
This question is formulated as an Assertion and a Reason and the possible answers are as follows: 
a) Both assertion and Reason are true and Reason is the correct explanation of the Assertion.
b) Both assertion and Reason are true but Reason is NOT the correct explanation of the Assertion.
c) Assertion is true but the Reason is false
d) Assertion is false but the Reason is true

**Question**:

**Assertion**: When the displacement of a body is directly proportional to the square of the time, then the body is moving with uniform acceleration. 
**Reason**: The slope of velocity time graph with time axis gives acceleration.

While I understand that both the Assertion and the Reason are true, **the key part I am interested in is, if the Reason correctly explains the Assertion or not (and why?).**

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

From **Newton's second law of Motion**, we have ***s = ut + ½ at²*** where s = displacement, u = initial velocity, v = final velocity, a = acceleration and t = time taken.

Putting initial velocity = 0, we have ***s = ½ at²*** i.e., ***s ∝ t²*** (a = constant).

Hence, one can conclude from the above equation that when the displacement of a body is directly proportional to the square of the time, the body is moving with uniform acceleration. However the above **Reason** does not explain this.

So, I think the answer will be **opt. b)**